CSP does not work as expected (it allows React SPA to load things when is set to 'none')
SPA & Network screenshot
I have a React SPA with only one request to my Node.js + express server with header "Content-Security-Policy" set to default-src 'none'. Although it still loads everything. What am I doing wrong? P.S: incognito mode does not help, I use latest version of Chrome.
I've checked syntax adding it to  tag and it worked but I want to be able to make my web app more secure via HTTP.

The Content-Security-Policy header must be sent with the HTML Doc response.
In your screenshot, it looks like the HTML Doc response doesn't have a Content-Security-Policy because your browser loaded the React app, which then fetched /ping.

Diagnosing your problem

In DevTools > Network, filter requests by the Doc type.

Here is your screenshot with the location of Doc circled in red.


Reload the page to capture the Doc response.
Does the Doc response have a Content-Security-Policy?


The CSP header must be on the client. If you want to protect the server, use CORS headers.
Example:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5139
